# Set up symfony4 URI with ONLY .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, symfony4

I am launching a symfony website on a server that can't be configured at all. So I can't touch the apache conf and all, I only have access to the drop repository.

So I need to use **ONLY** htaccess to :

1. point to the "public/index.php" file
2. Remove the "public" part from the url

I now have succeded the 1rst part with this in my lowest level .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php public/index.html
```

My second .htaccess is the basic one:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]


    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

How can I do the second part ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are solving things the other way around. The proper solution is described here https://medium.com/@runawaycoin/deploying-symfony-4-application-to-shared-hosting-with-just-ftp-access-e65d2c5e0e3d

> Upload the following folders (and contents) from your application to a new folder in your root of your FTP server named symfony:
>
> `bin
>   config
>   src
>   templates
>   translations
>   vendor`
>
> Note: Only upload the bin folder if you want to run the console, maybe via a cron job, also best to rename console to console.php
>
> Also create the var folder but dont upload its contents.
>
> And upload your composer.json file to this symfony folder — this is needed to help symfony find its application files.
>
> So you should have this on your server:
>
> `\symfony
>      bin
>      config
>      src
>      templates
>      translations
>      vendor
>      composer.json
>   \public_html
>      index.php
>      .htaccess
>      bundles
>      build`

Dont forget that you will need to modify index.php

> Before your application will work you need to modify your index.php file and set your env vars.
>
> First edit your index.php (locally inside your public folder, on the server will be inside your public_html folder).
>
> Edit this line:
>
> `require __DIR__.’/../vendor/autoload.php’;`
>
> To:
>
> `require __DIR__.’/../symfony/vendor/autoload.php’;`